# How to interpret this sentence, "Apple didn’t update the iPad Air, which could have hurt the sales numbers."

Tags: meaning

I found this sentence in [this article](http://techcrunch.com/2016/03/18/get-ready-for-the-new-ipad/).

> And yet, it’s a bit intriguing that Apple is choosing to raise the
>   price on the mainstream iPad. In the most recent quarter, iPad sales
>   were down 25 percent year-over-year. **Arguably, Apple didn’t update the
>   iPad Air, which could have hurt the sales numbers.** But it’s been an
>   ongoing trend for a couple of years now.

As an non native English speaker, it's difficult to understand the meaning of the sentence.

I think there are two possible ways to interpret it.

1.
If Apple had updated the iPad Air, it(=update) could have hurt the sales numbers.

2.
The fact that Apple didn't update the iPad Air might have hurt the sales number.

Comment: I think it's a "green dog vomit", a sentence that can be parsed differently, and you need to understand the context.

Comment: I agree, i don't think it's possible to say either way without context.  I think it's a poorly written sentence.

Comment: Where did you find that sentence?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I found this sentence in this article.  "Get ready for the new iPad" http://techcrunch.com/2016/03/18/get-ready-for-the-new-ipad/